# Редирект на swagger-ui/index.html#/ SpringDoc

Tags: java, url, swagger, openapi, swaggerui

Создал конфигурации OpenApi

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Application.properties

```
 springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
 springdoc.swagger-ui.path=swagger-ui.html
```

При переходе по http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ происходит редирект на http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/.

Необходимо избавиться от этого редиректа и получать контент по адресу http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/